# Unable to fetch with formData using nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to NextJS and I'm trying to figure out server action.

I have this request.

```js
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function submitIPCR(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
  // @ts-ignore
  try {
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData), 'waaa', formData)
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/ipcr", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: formData
    });

    console.log(res.statusText)
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Something wrong')

    await res.json()
    revalidatePath('/ipcr/new');
    return { message: 'Successfully' }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return { message: 'Error' }
  }

}
```

but I always get this error when I check the network.

Error: Bad request

```
{"message":"Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0","error":"Bad Request","statusCode":400}
```

I use the fetch on form like this.

```js
const NewIPCR = () => {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(submitIPCR, initState);

  return (
    <div>
      <form action={formAction}>
       {redacted}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewIPCR;
```

And the confusing part is, it's not even hitting my server. I use https://hoppscotch.io/ and my request is fine, but when I'm on nextJS I have an error. Not sure how to fix since the response is not coming from my server.

Also when I try to format the fetch request body to.

```js
 const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/ipcr", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: {
        ratee: ''
      }
    });
```

I get an overload error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ratee' does not exist in type 'ReadableStream<any> | Blob | ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | FormData | URLSearchParams'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ratee' does not exist in type 'ReadableStream<any> | Blob | ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | FormData | URLSearchParams'.ts(2769)
```

I didn't even add a type on body or fetch. not sure where is this coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to parse form data, but on the example on MDN they just sent raw form data without parsing. what I did is this.

```js
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
```

this fixes my problem.